# javascript, looping fields and validating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using below code to check some form fields and render datatable table on a button click. My intention is to stop the table from being rendered if any of the fields are empty. Apparently `return false` inside the loop is not working.

Is this the correct way to accomplish? any better ways?

```
$('#advance_search').click(function(){
  var ds = $('.advance_search .filter_field');

  $.each(ds, function(index, value){ //this loop checks for series of fields
    if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
      alert('Please fill in '+$(this).data('label'));
      return false;
    }
  });

  dt.fnDraw(); //shouldn't be called if either one of the field is empty

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a control variable to prevent the `dt.fnDraw()` from being called:

```
$('#advance_search').click(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();

  var check = 0, // Control variable
      ds    = $('.advance_search .filter_field');

  $.each(ds, function(index, value){ //this loop checks for series of fields
    if($(this).val().length === 0) {
      check++; // error found, increment control variable
      alert('Please fill in '+$(this).data('label'));
    }
  });

  if (check==0) { // Enter only if the control variable is still 0
    dt.fnDraw(); //shouldn't be called if either one of the field is empty
  }

});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look carefully, your `return false` is inside the `$.each` callback function, so it `returns false` for the caller of that function, not the "main function" you are in.

Try this:

```
$('#advance_search').click(function(){
    var ds = $('.advance_search .filter_field'), valid = true;

    $.each(ds, function(index, value){ //this loop checks for series of fields
        if($(this).val().length === 0) {
            alert('Please fill in '+$(this).data('label'));
            return (valid = false); //return false and also assign false to valid
        }
    });

    if( !valid ) return false;

    dt.fnDraw(); //shouldn't be called if either one of the field is empty

});
```